# PDO Connection Password can't have $ # ! characters

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I use ! @ # $ in my MySQL user's password

but when using these characters in my password, PDO can't connect to MySQL server

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "test";
$password = "!@#$test";
$dbname = "test";

try {
  $test = $_POST['test'];
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, 
  $password, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
  // set the PDO error mode to exception
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

  // prepare sql and bind parameters
  $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO test (test) 
  VALUES (:test)");
  $stmt->bindParam(':test', $test);


  $stmt->execute();
```

It gives this error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'test'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

when removing !@#$ from password it works correctly

Comment: Turn on error reporting and you'll see the problem.`error_reporting(E_ALL);` & `ini_set("display_errors",1);`

Comment: have you tried "SET NAMES utf8" => "SET NAMES 'utf8'"

Comment: it's because of the double quotes, it has nothing to do with UTF-8

Comment: I should be posting that ^ as an answer.

Comment: Same as why `echo "!@#$test";` displays only `!@#` and generates a notice.

Comment: @AbraCadaver exactly. +1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This has nothing to do with UTF-8.

PHP thinks you have a variable name with a `$` assigned to it.

The `$password = "!@#$test";` with the double quotes is technically looking for a variable called `$test` and is trying to parse it.

It needs to be in single quotes:

```
$password = '!@#$test';
```

Note: The `!` and `@` also have special meaning in PHP.

- `!` is `not`.
- `@` is an error suppressor and a character used in email.
- `#` is a comment character.

Theoretically, error reporting *should* have thrown you a notice about an undefined variable.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

UTF-8 deals with queries and characters that won't display correctly when querying, depending on the db's/table's collation.

If and when that you start seeing `?` in your query's output, then you would need to set the connection's DSN to UTF-8.

This is covered in the following Q&A:

- [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: But `!@#` don't have any special meaning in a double-quoted string.

Comment: @AbraCadaver true, I just thought I'd note it "after" ;-)

Comment: for future reference OP, `error_reporting(E_ALL);` & `ini_set("display_errors",1);` will save a lot of headaches.

Comment: @WheatBeak yes thanks. Matter of fact, I was adding the error reporting to answer.

Comment: @Fred-ii- it might be worth adding to your answering explaining how OP can include `$` in their password.  EDIT, oh I just saw you did, was that there before? :P

Comment: @WheatBeak the password assignment in single quotes should cover it as shown in the answer, or have I missed something? Edit: saw your edit too *lol*

Comment: @WheatBeak hehe no worries.

Comment: Of course if you really wanted to get technical there's `$password = "!@#\$test";`  ;)

Comment: Just personal preference really, I hate mixing `"` and `'` so for me it would be either change everything to `'` or just escape the `$`